# Unity Gone after reboot..Nvidia Issue

Tags: unity, 12.10, nvidia, compiz

First off, I am aware similar issues have been posted by others. I have exhausted the options I have found within those topics that I have found, and none have helped. I have tried things ranging from reinstalling compiz, making sure that it is in fact enabled by running ccsm blah blah blah. The following is where I am at-----

So I am a support tech for Widnows based PC's and trying to learn Linux. I have Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 dual booting in UEFI on my Asus G75-VW with the Nvidia 660m. Both boot Fine.

Upon first boot of Ubuntu after an install, the desktop is fine, resolution is at 1080p, but it says compiz unexpectedly quits repeatedly, although everything continues to work fine. After rebooting or shutting down, things go haywire.

When trying to boot back into Ubuntu 12.10, I just get a all purple screen with some weird black fuzzy bars at the top. I got past this by booting to recovery, going to root terminal, and typing the following:

```
rm -Rfv ~/.compiz-1
rm -Rfv ~/.config/compiz-1
reboot now
```

This gets me back to the login screen but at a much reduced resolution and no Unity. I can play around with the different drivers here by right clicking the desktop, hittng change background, hitting All Settings, Software sources, and then Additional drivers, however all end up either the same or with just a black screen no mouse.

The only way at this point I can get unity and 1080p back is too hit `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F1` and type:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo reboot now
```

At this point, compiz no longer crashes and all works great for my minimal purposes. However, thats a lot of work to do everytime I want to boot into Ubuntu. When its working, additional drivers says it is using an ALTERNATIVE driver. All the other drivers fail and it always defaults to one of them on reboot.

Can anyone offer some suggestions? It doesn't seem like it is Unity/Compiz that is the issue as much as it is a driver problem, but I could very well be mistaken. When any of those drivers load I am stuck in low resolutions.

Perhaps a temporary solution if not a fix, possibly a way to keep it using the alternative driver if an nvidia one can not work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ubuntu-guia.com/2012/10/instalar-controlador-nvidia-en-ubuntu.html

The blog is in Spanish, translate it with goole please.
It is very good blog about ubuntu